# best way in python to extract specific info from columns of data in text file

Tags: python

I currently have multiple txt files with two columns of data: wavenumber and intensity:

```
500.21506 0.00000
500.45613 0.00000
500.69720 0.00000
500.93826 0.00000
501.17933 0.00000
501.42040 0.00000
501.66147 0.00000
501.90253 0.00000
502.14360 0.00000
502.38467 0.00000
502.62574 0.00000
502.86680 0.00000
503.10787 0.00000
```

I need to write a code that can extract the intensity values in between a minimum and maximum wavenumber and print only the intensities corresponding to those in a list in an output file. However, I am having trouble switching between list and float type. Here is what I have:

```
with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
    for line in g:
        parts = line.split()
        parts = float(parts)
        if parts[0] >= lowwav and parts[0],= highwav:
            f.write(parts[1])
            f.write('\n')
        else: break
```

Currently `parts` is a list type, but when I attempt to force it to a float for comparison (`parts = float(parts)`), I get this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I am new to python so I would appreciate suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Try using `lowwav <= parts[0] <= highwav` for readability.

Comment: What are you expecting `float(parts)` to do, *exactly*? What would you want from an input of `['5.2', '3.5']`?

Comment: I need the parts of the list to appear as float items so they will compare to the variables lowwav and highwav which are floats

Comment: What type are you expecting `parts` to be, after running `float(parts)`?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to *call `float()` on a list* of strings. Instead, call it on individual strings:

```
parts = [float(item) for item in line.split()]
```

Comment: implemented it - it still claims that it is a 'list' and doesn't compare my values

Comment: @alli have you removed the `parts = float(parts)` line?

Comment: @alli okay, what error are getting now and on which line? Thanks.

Comment: no error, but when I command print type(parts) it is still 'list' and the comparisons are not happening - my output doesn't print any intensity values

Comment: @alli yes, `parts` would still be a list, but now with float items which you then compare with `lowwav` and `highwav`.

Comment: ok but it is still not printing out the intensities that I intend - do you know why that may be occurring?

Comment: @alli you need to debug how the if condition works in your case. Use a debugger or simply add print statements to observe the `parts[0]` value and how does it compare with `lowwav` and `highwav`..